# Why don't I get an error when I reference a id that hasn't been flagged with "@+id"?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm referencing @id/action_profile before assigning @+id/action_profile. Why doesn't this give me an error? Is it because the ids are assigned in R.java and the attributes are assigned at runtime?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/action_profile"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_profile"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/profile_icon"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to talk about this topic, we need to have a solid foundation of understanding about what the `android:id` and `android:layout_toLeftOf` attributes (and any other attribute that expects an id resource) actually "do".

They only set `int` fields on their `View` (or their View's `LayoutParams` object).

These `int` fields can then later be used to specify behavior, but as far as the `<TextView>` tag is concerned, all that `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/action_profile"` means is "store `R.id.action_profile` as the id of the view I should position myself to the left of". There is no top-down parsing of the text file to look for whether or not a view tag with that id was already previously declared. The TextView is just saving an `int` for later.

In fact, taking it to an extreme, the following is perfectly legal:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/some_other_id"
        android:text="hello world"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There's nothing in this layout with the id `some_other_id`, so how could my TextView be below it? Well, if you run this app, it just positions itself at the top-left, because it couldn't find the view I was referring to.

The reason this *compiles* is that I have a different layout file in my project:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/some_other_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I'm hiding!"/>
```

This layout file isn't used in my activity. It has nothing to do with the first example at all. But all that matters is that it has `@+id/some_other_id` in it. This causes `R.id.some_other_id` to be created, and then my first layout is quite happy to use it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think that is what the OP was asking. What I think is being asked:  reading the layout file from top to bottom a `View` is referencing another `Object` in the list of attributes before the `Object` has been "declared" ...In this case the attribute  `layout_toLeftOf="@id/action_profile"` is referencing the `LinearLayout` object by its `id` "action_profile" before that object has been "declared". Kind of like trying to read the value of a method variable before that variable has been declared inside the method.

Comment: @ZackRobinson I've updated my answer to attempt to clarify